# Pulling a vec out of a vec of structs

Tags: rust

I'm working on a compiler for a toy language and I want to be able to check for errors on each file. I have a `MooFile` struct that has a `Vec<anyhow::Error>` where I put errors when they are encountered. Now I want to go through the files, get the errors, and flatten that into a single vec to return from the compiler but I'm running up against the borrow checker. I'm going to post my various attempt but they keep running into similar issues.

```
fn compile(&mut self) -> Result<(), Vec<Error>> {
    ...
    // Check for errors
    let has_errors = self.files
        .iter()
        .map(|file| file.has_errors())
        .reduce(|acc, value| acc | value)
        .unwrap_or(false);

     if has_errors {
        let mut errors = vec![];
        self.files
            .iter()
            .for_each(|&mut file| errors.append(&mut file.errors));

        Err(errors)
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `file.errors` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src\lib.rs:62:48
   |
62 |                 .for_each(|file| errors.append(&mut file.errors));
   |                            ----                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `file` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
   |                            |
   |                            help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut MooFile`
```

```
fn compile(&mut self) -> Result<(), Vec<Error>> {
    ...
    // Check for errors
    let has_errors = self.files
        .iter()
        .map(|file| file.has_errors())
        .reduce(|acc, value| acc | value)
        .unwrap_or(false);

    if has_errors {
        let mut errors = vec![];
        self.files
            .into_iter()
            .for_each(|mut file| errors.append(&mut file.errors));

        Err(errors)
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.files` which is behind a mutable reference
   --> src\lib.rs:63:13
    |
63  |             self.files
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.files` has type `Vec<MooFile>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
64  |                 .into_iter()
    |                  ----------- `self.files` moved due to this method call
```

```
fn compile(&mut self) -> Result<(), Vec<Error>> {
    ...
    // Check for errors
    let errors: Vec<Error> = self.files
        .iter()
        .map(|file| file.errors)
        .flatten()
        .collect();

    if errors.len() > 0 {
        Err(errors)
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `file.errors` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src\lib.rs:54:25
   |
54 |             .map(|file| file.errors)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `file.errors` has type `Vec<anyhow::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `moo2` due to previous error
```

I feel like there has to be some kind of idiomatic way of doing this kind of thing that I'm missing.

Comment: Unrelated to the main question, but I'd suggest switching from `map` / `reduce`, which are going to iterate over the whole set of files, to `any`, which will stop iterating once the predicate is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these errors come from how you create your iterators. If you assume `x` is a `Vec<Y>`:

- `x.iter()`: Consumes `&x` and creates an iterator of `&Y`.
- `x.iter_mut()`: Consumes `&mut x` and creates an iterator of `&mut Y`.
- `x.into_iter()`: Consumes ownership of the entire `Vec<Y>` and creates an iterator of owned `Y`.

The first version uses `.iter()` when you want a mutable reference (`.iter_mut()`). The second uses `.into_iter()` when you want a mutable reference (`.iter_mut()`). And the third uses `.iter()` when you attempt to claim ownership of the errors by disposing of the files (`.into_iter()`, but you can't drop `self.files` without issues).

Here is one way you could `Clone` the errors without moving them out of each `file`.

```rust
let mut errors = Vec::new();

self.files.iter()
    .filter(|file| file.has_errors())
    .foreach(|file| errors.extend_from_slice(&file.errors));

if has_errors {
    return Err(errors)
}
Ok(())
```

Or you could `drain` them into a new `Vec` using `extend`. This version also uses `any` to look a bit cleaner, but is not as efficient.

```rust
if self.files.iter().any(|f| f.has_errors()) {
    let mut errors = Vec::new();

    for file in &mut self.files {
        errors.extend(file.errors.drain(..));
    }

    return Err(errors)
}

Ok(())
```

Comment: `append()` with `&mut` reference is also fine.